# printf 0 with 0 precision

Tags: c, printf

I have being wondering why `printf("%.d", 0);` outputs nothing, whereas it outputs something for any other number than 0, and `printf("%d", 0);` outputs '0' as expected.

The only difference between the 2 codes is the precision. Here is what the documentation says about the precision :

> An optional precision, in the form of a period . followed by an
>            optional digit string.  If the digit string is omitted, the precision
>            is taken as zero.  This gives the **minimum** number of digits to appear
>            for d, i, o, u, x, and X conversions.

In that case the precision should just be ignored, no?

Comment: You might want to read some other documentation, for example [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (which is usually very accurate) which says "If both the converted value and the precision are ​0​ the conversion results in no characters."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X): precision specifies the minimum number of digits to be written. If the value to be written is shorter than this number, the result is padded with leading zeros. The value is not truncated even if the result is longer. **A precision of 0 means that no character is written for the value 0.**

Don't know why though, probably has to do with the way C handles NULL pointers, or as @TripeHound pointed out, it could be a design decision.

Comment: Okay, then I should maybe stop using the man on my computer ;)

Comment: The man on your computer refers to the base printf function, not the c wrapper.  I'm guessing there's a conflict between 0 and NULL; if you have time `info coreutils 'printf invocation'` gives you the full man page.

Comment: My guess is that it's nothing to do with `NULL`s but simply so you can chose to leave zero-values as blanks (like spreadsheets tend to allow).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting thing that in alternate form (# flag) for x and X specifiers:

> 0x or 0X is prefixed to results if the converted value is **nonzero**.

For example, `printf("a = %#.0x", 0);` results in "a = "

But for o specifier:

> In the alternative implementation precision is increased if necessary,
>   to write one leading zero. In that case if both the converted value
>   and the precision are ​0​, single ​0​ is written.

So, `printf("a = %#.0o", 0);` results in "a = 0"